# Div onclick toggle needs two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of jquery, which toggles a div on click. My problem is it at first needs two clicks to show the div, afterwards it toggles the div as expected. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for suggestions.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#clickme" ).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var categories = $("#categories");
            if (!categories.data("loaded")) {
                categories.load("/categories");
                categories.data("loaded", true);
            }
            categories.slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the if block of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most possibly because `#categories` div is not hidden before and it doesn't have content in it. So when you do first load it will load the data but you do a slideToggle immediately so the div's state gets toggle it becomes hidden, and you dont do a load anymore and the second click actually them toggles again and makes it visible. Also use a callback on load and initially hide the div.

Ex:

```
#categories{
   display:none;
}
```

and

```
$(function() {
        //if you dont want to specify css then do this first up.
        $("#categories").hide();
        //now your click event
        $( "#clickme" ).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var categories = $("#categories");

           if (categories.data("loaded")) {
               categories.slideToggle("fast");
               return;
           }

           categories.load("/categories", function(){
                categories.data("loaded", true).slideDown("fast");
           });
        });
    });
```

*Note that slideToggle toggles the current state of the div, if it is visible and have no content it, it will still hide it on the first click*

Your issue is well demonstrated here **[Demo-Issue](http://jsfiddle.net/wDGMa/)**

and you can fix that by **[Demo-Fix](http://jsfiddle.net/ACDV4/)**

Comment: Perfect, display:none; did it. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe at start the div is visible (without content).
On first click, it loads the content but hides the content (slideToggle)
On second click, content is already loaded and its showed by slideToggle.

Comment: Perfect, display:none; did it. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

What happened in my case is even after hiding the div 2 clicks  needed to toggle for the first time.

```
<div id="wholeinf1_<?php echo $res['userid']; ?>" style="height:auto; width:auto; display:none;">
<div id="wholeinf_<?php echo $res['userid']; ?>" style="height:auto; width:auto;"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.other_chart').live("click",function(){
        //e.preventDefault();
        var userid2= $(this).attr("id").split('_').pop();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "index.php",
        data: "userid="+ userid2,
        cache: false,
        //beforesend: function(){$(".podar").show();},
        success: function(html) {
              //$("#loader_"+userid1).hide();
              $("#wholeinf1_"+userid2).toggle();
                  $("#wholeinf_"+userid2).empty().append(html);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I did on this is, I put the div which will load the data into another div & toggled the outer division. Thats worked smooth for me.

I guess this will be helpful to someone in the years to come.